# When trying to use the command mingw32-make, the system returns a compatibility error

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, makefile, mingw

When trying to run the command `mingw32-make` in the `openCV/opencv/release` folder, it gives the error below. The system used is 64-bit, but I haven't found any command to replace it. I'm trying to integrate QT with OpenCV, and I've already installed CMake. Here's the error:

```
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a(vs_version.rc.obj)' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:1919: bin/libopencv_core470.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1878: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

I tried to install mingw64 and added many different PATHs for the various MinGW installations I've done, but it didn't work. I've installed several MinGWs, but I don't know another way to integrate the components.

Comment: When you compiled the file `vs_version.rc.obj` you compiled it as a 32bit object file not a 64bit object file.  Since you didn't provide any information on how that object file was created, that's all we can say.  Note, this has nothing to do with `make`.  Make is just a tool that invokes commands.  Your makefile needs to tell it the right commands to invoke.

Comment: I just deleted the folder where I used CMake, I ran the steps and the command again and everything was fine. I think it was a crash error when I first ran it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the folder where I used CMake, I ran the steps and the command again and everything was fine. I think it was a crash error when I first ran it